# How to save data from textview on sqlite database and JSON parse that data in android

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-sqlite, arrays

I am getting GetVehicles method of SOAP WSDL from SOAP web services and call that GetVehicles result in TextView when clicking on a Button event.
there is one button and one  TextView in my xml.

when I run program the data is shown in textview , I want to store or save that result shown in TextView in Sqlite database?.
I have created DatabaseHandler class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.
I am passing these two parameters which are for id and name,

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
public class GetVehiclesActivity extends Activity {

    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetServerVehicles";

    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME = "GetServerVehicles";

    private static String URL = "http://favouritehatfield.co.uk/Service1.asmx?";        
    private TextView txtV_vehicles;

    private long clientid=46;

    private String response;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.getvehicles);

        /** Show Toast at the Start of Activity... **/
        Toast.makeText(this, "WELCOME to GET VEHICLES ACTIVITY..", 1).show();

        txtV_vehicles = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtV_lbl_vehicles);

         DatabaseHandler db = new  DatabaseHandler(this);

    }//End onCreate()

    private class vehiclesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            txtV_vehicles.setText(response);

        }//End onPostExecute()

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();

        }//End onPreExecute()

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       SoapObject getVehiclesRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
            // add paramaters and values

            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("defaultclientId");
            pi.type= PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS;
            getVehiclesRequest.addProperty(pi,46);

            PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
            pi2.setName("hashKey");
            pi2.type= PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            getVehiclesRequest.addProperty(pi2,"464321orue");

       SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12); 

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(getVehiclesRequest);  
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            //httpTransport.debug = true;  

            try {
                httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();    
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
            SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
                response = result.toString();
            } catch (SoapFault e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  


            return null;
        }//End doInBackground

    }// End vehiclesAsyncTask


    /** Called when the user clicks the GetVehicles button */
    public void getVehicle(View v) {
         String str = "You have clicked GetVehicles ...";
            Toast.makeText(this, str, 0).show();

        vehiclesAsyncTask vehiclesRequest = new vehiclesAsyncTask();
        vehiclesRequest.execute();
       //       
    }//End getVehicle()

    /** Called when the user clicks the SAVEDATA button  I want this buton to save the  TextView result in SQLite Database*/

    /** Called when the user clicks the SAVEDATA button */
public void saveData(View v) {

     String str = "Save DAta Button Clicked ...";
     Toast.makeText(this, str, 0).show();

    String s1 = txtV_vehicles.getText().toString();

    Objdbhandler.saveVehicles(s1, s1, s1, s1, s1);

//  Objdbhandler.saveVehicles(Name, TotalPassengers, TotalHandLuggages, TotalLugages, SortOderNo)

}//End saveData(...) Method
```

}//End class  GetVehiclesActivity

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any clue.
How can I do that?

Comment: I am passing these two parameters which are for id and name,                                  PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
   pi.setName("defaultclientId");
  // pi.setValue(clientid);
   pi.type= PropertyInfo.LONG_CLASS;
   getVehiclesRequest.addProperty(pi,46);
  
   
   PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
   pi2.setName("hashKey");
  // pi.setValue(clientid);
   pi2.type= PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
   getVehiclesRequest.addProperty(pi2,"464321orue");

Comment: are you trying to insert in 2 different databases because i can see 'defaultclientId' and 'mensagens' in `db.insert()` command ?

Comment: any exception in log cat?

Comment: no defaultclientid and hashcode is my two parameters. mensagens is commented should not be read. This data is comming from SOAP web services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that DatabaseHandler() is working correctly. As per code sample, the problem I can see that you have written

```
cValues.put("defaultclientId", "clientidclientid");
db.insert("defaultclientId", null, cValues);
```

here you are passing databaseName same as columnName in insert query. The correct usage of  insert query is as follows:

```
public long insert (String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

where

```
table:=the table to insert the row into
nullColumnHack:=optional; may be null. 
values:=this map contains the initial column values for the row. The keys should be the column names and the values the column values
```

So, you should insert in database by using below code:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); 
values.put("defaultclientId", "put_default_client_id_received_from_SOAP"); 
values.put("hashkey", "put_hashkey_received");
database.insert("database_name", null, values);
```

Hope this clears things!!

Comment: I have find a 75% soultion by assigning TextView object txtV_vehicles to a String s1 :     /** Called when the user clicks the SAVEDATA button */
 public void saveData(View v) {
  
   String str = "Save DAta Button Clicked ...";
   Toast.makeText(this, str, 0).show();
  
  String s1 = txtV_vehicles.getText().toString();
  
  Objdbhandler.saveVehicles(s1, s1, s1, s1, s1);
    
 }//End saveData(...) Method      BUT IT's NOT GIVING ME TE ACTUAL DATA TO BE STORED IN REQUIRED COLUMN .    MY SAVEVEHICLE INSERTION METHOD IN DATABASEHANDLER CLASS HAVE FOLLOWING PARAMETERS:

Comment: saveVehicles(Name, TotalPassengers, TotalHandLuggages, TotalLugages, SortOderNo)

Comment: public boolean saveVehicles(String Name, String TotalPassengers, String TotalHandLuggages,String TotalLugages, String SortOderNo) {
  objSQLitedb = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  
  initialValues.put(VEHICLE_COLUMN_NAME, Name);
  
  // HERE I'M PUTTING ALL (KEYS,VALUES); 
  initialValues.put(VEHICLE_COLUMN_ZSORTORDERNO, SortOderNo);
        objSQLitedb.insert(VEHICLE_TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
  objSQLitedb.close();
  return true;
 }//End of method saveVehicles(...)

Comment: this data of insertVehicle method is shown in all columns but whole bellow data is simultaneously shown in the all columns of TABLE  This thing is coming in all Columns [{"Id":35,"Name":"Saloon","TotalPassengers":4,"TotalHandLuggages":2,"TotalLuggages":2,"SortOrderNo:0"}]
 , I know it is because Objdbhandler.saveVehicles(s1,s1,s1,s1,s1);         I want Id to store in Id column , Name into Name column ,Should I do it in JSon Parsing or any other way kindly guide me.

Comment: Yes, here are the steps you can follow , when you come to saveData function:
1. Parse the data using Json apis available in the android. Write  function which will return parsed data. You can also create POJO class to hold different fields in Json response and return it from parse method. Or just store it hashmap with keys and values.

2. Then pass this data to saveVehicles(PARSED_DATA) method.
3. Now in saveVehicle method you can put data in ContentValues and insert in database.

Comment: You can refer to http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ and 
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ tutorials. 

Hope this will help !!

Comment: tHIS IS MY jSON aRRAY RESPONSE IN tEXTVIEW.           [ 
   { 
 "Id":350,
      "Name":"Saloon",
      "TotalPassengers":4, 
      "TotalHandLuggages":2, 
      "TotalLuggages":2, 
       "SortOrderNo":0
 },  
{
"Id":351,
"Name":"Estate",
"TotalPassengers":4,
"TotalHandLuggages":2,
"TotalLuggages":4,
"SortOrderNo":1
 },

{
"Id":801,
"Name":"Ford Galaxy Passengers Only",
"TotalPassengers":6,
"TotalHandLuggages":0,
"TotalLuggages":0,
"SortOrderNo":5
 }
   ];
}

Comment: LOGcat :  06-20 15:22:37.556: W/System.err(30087): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"Name":"Saloon","SortOrderNo":0,"TotalHandLuggages":2,"Id":350,"TotalPassengers":4,"TotalLuggages":2},{"Name":"MPV","SortOrderNo":2,"TotalHandLuggages":3,"Id":352,"TotalPassengers":5,"TotalLuggages":5},{"Name":"8 Seater","SortOrderNo":3,"TotalHandLuggages":8,"Id":377,"TotalPassengers":8,"TotalLuggages":8},{"Name":"Ford Galaxy Passengers Only","SortOrderNo":5,"TotalHandLuggages":0,"Id":801,"TotalPassengers":6,"TotalLuggages":0}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: I have solved this Question problem. Now How can I close this question.